# Generation of Referral or coupon code

Tags: java, mysql, spring

How can I generate readable referral code for users. I am using Java 7 programming language and MySQL db. I am searching for this from week but not getting appropriate solution.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of referral code do you want. If you be a little more verbose, that would help most of us a million

Comment: Like for sharing app, each user has their own unique referral code

Comment: Do you want to generate something like a Coupon Code?

Comment: @ZishanMohsin I meant like alphanumeric/numeric , &  what MySql db has to do in it. Will it even matter which DB you r using in here ?

Comment: Yes alphanumeric. I mentioned db name because I thought that it may happen that MySQL have some kind of feature which I don't know.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in java

Comment: Also, we have more than 15 lakh user in our db, so it should be unique also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For maintaining *Uniqueness* keep the `codeLength` as large as you can means atleast `6` or `8`. Also you can include capital Alphabets also in `chars` array so that uniqueness also can get increased as more combinations can be served. Including capital letters also, you can serve upto 64^8 unique random codes ideally.

```
   public String createRandomCode(int codeLength){   
     char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
        return output ;
    }
```

Comment: How many random and unique code can be generated using above code?

Comment: Can not be provided accurately the number but it will be better to keep the `chars` and `codeLength` as large as you can.

Comment: Do you know ola, snapdeal apps?? How they are handling referral code for each user? Even their code length is not more than 8 character

Comment: I don't work in any of these mentioned companies. But most probably in terms of Java. they also might be using the same/similar logic

Comment: After including capital letters and code length to 8, your code can serve upto 1097759 random code without uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: Randomness of secure random will get lost, if jvm is restarted.

Comment: If your math is correct, after including capital letters and code length to 8 , you can serve upto  64^8 unique random codes